# onClick() en button aplica a todo el formulario

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
php

 <td style="width: 10%"><button id="additionalLeakage" onClick="mostrarAdditionalLeakage()">Additional Leakage Area</button></td>

js

function mostrarAdditionalLeakage(e){
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();     
            console.log('fyfyduydutrd');    
        }
    });
        if ($('#tablaHoldTimeAlt').css('display')=='block') {
            $('#tablaLeakageArea').css('display', 'none');
            $('#tablaHoldTimeAlt').css('display', 'none');

        } else if ($('#tablaHoldTimeAlt').css('display')==('none')) {
            $('#tablaLeakageArea').css('display', 'block');
            $('#tablaHoldTimeAlt').css('display', 'block');
        }
    }
```

Estoy usando el botton Addiotional Leakage Area para desplegar y esconder las dos tablas, Leakage Area Calculations y Hold Time Estimates, esto funciona bien, el problema es que cuando presiono enter, tambien se cierra y abre, cuando esto solo se deberia hacer onClick, lo necesito porque al introducir valores en n Assumed y Add Hole y presionar enter para que se calcule, se cierra la pestaña y poniendo un e.preventDefault() como en el js que he adjuntado se aplica al boton pero tambien a los campos de dentro, sabeis porque onClick esta aplicando a campos fuera del propio button? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero si el botón tiene el foco, presionar "enter" es como darle click... es eso lo que preguntas?

Comment: @Pipe si, no habria forma de que no lo hiciese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es agregar el evento fuera del click, para que desde un inicio se bloquee el enter (y opcionalmente supongo que quieres bloquear tambien la barra espaciadora, que tiene el mismo efecto sobre el botón)

```js
$("#additionalLeakage").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13 || event.which === 32) { //Bloqueas ENTER y Barra Espaciadora
      event.preventDefault();     
      console.log('Fue un ENTER, accion detenida');    
  }
});

function mostrarAdditionalLeakage(e){
    console.log("ejecutando accion");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td style="width: 10%"><button id="additionalLeakage" onClick="mostrarAdditionalLeakage()">Additional Leakage Area</button></td>
```